# How do I prevent this last "broken condition" from being pushed to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, slice

I am dynamically slicing an array, and I can get the functionality I want by simply removing the last element with `arr.pop()` but I want to know exactly why my `while` loop is adding this to my array when it breaks my conditional.

```
slices(num){
    let arr = [this.digits.slice(0, num)]
    let i = 0
    if (this.digits.length < num){
            throw new Error('Slice size is too big.')
    } else {
        while (arr[i].length === num){
            i++
            arr.push(this.digits.slice(i, num + i))
        }
        // arr.pop() - removed for testing
        return arr
    }
}
```

Here is an example.  Let's say we want to slice this array:

```
this.digits = [ 3, 1, 0, 0, 1 ]
```

Ideally, our output will look like this:

```
[3, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

With my current code and without using `arr.pop()`, my algorithim will consistently sneak in an extra slice iteration that has less length than what my conditional is asking for (in this case, `num == 3`)

This will be my output:

```
[[3, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

I know there are many ways to do this, but for this, I would like to maintain the integrity of my code, so a solution that uses my implementation would be great :D

EDIT:  I get why the last element is being added.  Since the element before fulfills the conditional (it's length is equal to num), it moves on to the next iteration but how I do handle it eloquently without using .pop()

EDIT:  Thanks all for the answers!  They all seem like they would work, but Peter B's implementation was so very clean, especially given that he changed just a few lines for me and it worked like a charm.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking the wrong condition in the `while`. It is better to calculate how many sub-arrays you are going to add inside the `while` (in addition to the one that you start with), and count up to that number, like this:

```js
var digits = [3, 1, 0, 0, 1];

function slices(num) {
  let arr = [this.digits.slice(0, num)]
  let i = 0
  if (this.digits.length < num) {
    throw new Error('Slice size is too big.')
  } else {
    var sliceCutoff = this.digits.length - num;
    while (i < sliceCutoff) {
      i++
      arr.push(this.digits.slice(i, num + i))
    }
    return arr
  }
}

console.log(slices(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the leftover items are enough to get an array with the wanted length. That means, you need a single loop with a continuing check for the actual ster index, wanted size and the length.

An approach by checking the last array after splicing is unnecessary, because it generates an avoidable overhead.

```js
function slice(array, n) {
    var result = [], 
        start = 0;
    
    while (start + n <= array.length) {
        result.push(array.slice(start, start++ + n));
    }
    return result;
}

var array = [3, 1, 0, 0, 1];

console.log(slice(array, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Description

I believe that you're looking for something along the lines of this? As you can see, I've also removed some redundant code, i.e. using a `while` loop in this scenario and the `else` clause.

I've also just declared `digits` as a parameter for this demo, I believe that you'd have the initiative to be able to change this to your application(s) requirement(s) without much/any assistance.

```js
function slices(digits, num) {
  const arr = [];

  if (digits.length < num)
    throw new Error('Slice size is too big.')

  for (let i = 0; i != num; i++)
    arr.push(digits.slice(i, num + i));

  return arr;
}

var d = [3, 1, 0, 0, 1]; // Only here for the demo.
console.log(slices(d, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're really close. I think my proposed solution here keeps the general idea of yours. The problem you're hitting is that checking `arr[i].length` being equal to `num` means this is only checking the last item you added to the array, not the next one. Instead, check the item you're about to add.

```js
this.digits = [ 3, 1, 0, 0, 1 ];

function slices(num) {
    let arr = []
    let i = 0
    if (this.digits.length < num) {
            throw new Error('Slice size is too big.')
    } else {
        while (this.digits.slice(i, num + i).length === num){
            arr.push(this.digits.slice(i, num + i))
            i++
        }
        // arr.pop() - removed for testing
        return arr
    }
}

console.log(slices(3));
```